# typescript still complains after hasOwnProperty check

Tags: typescript

There is a type like this

```
export type PathType =
  | LivingstoneSouthernWhiteFacedOwl
  | ArakGroundhog
  | HubsCampaigns
  | HubsCampaignsItemID
  | HubsAlgos
  | HubsAlgosItemID
  | TartuGecko
  | HammerfestPonies
  | TrapaniSnowLeopard
  | BeijingPigeon
  | Link
  | LinksMhdSwsVisordeltas
  | MetadatahandlingName
  | MetadatahandlingGetmetadataSequencesNameSequenceNameLabelNameLabelName;
```

These are interfaces of open API definition paths.

And I need to write a function like this one

```
import { PathType } from '../types/path.type';

const makeFormJSONSchema = (path: PathType) => {
  const schema = {};
  // 1. If there are any `parameters` put them into the schema
  if (path.hasOwnProperty('parameters')) {
    path.parameters;
  }
  // 2. then peek at the method object by the `method` prop
  // 3. Check for additional `parameters` and put into the schema
  // 4. Check for `requestBody` and put into the schema

  return schema;
};

export default makeFormJSONSchema;
```

Here as you can see I check if the `path` object got the `parameters` property then try to access it.

However typescript gives an error

[image]

How can we tell typescript that yes we got this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PathType is a union type, you can **only** access properties of common properties of all its unioned types.
Therefore you need to define a type guard that will somehow assure Typescript that an object is of a given type.

Let's assume that BeijingPigeon and TartuGecko both contain the property 'parameters'.

Create the type guards:

```
function isBeijingPigeon(val: PathType): val is BeijingPigeon {
    return (val as BeijingPigeon).parameters !== undefined;
}
function isTartuGecko (val: PathType): val is TartuGecko {
    return (val as TartuGecko).parameters !== undefined;
}
```

Then whenever you need to access the parameters property, do this:

```
if (isBeijingPigeon(pathObject) || isTartuGecko(pathObject) {
   // access to pathObject.parameters won't cause any errors
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: This answers the exact question as such, thank you. 

However I'd like to point out also a subtle issue I was pointed at. It's a bit of design issue as well. Properly abstracted interface instead of union types is much better to use for the purpose of this function. In case of open API, types here will be helpful https://github.com/metadevpro/openapi3-ts

Comment: I agree, creating a union type of a dozen or more types doesn't make for such legible code and it should probably have been done in a different way. But I haven't seen the rest of your code so you might have been forced to do it that way.
There's always a context that we as readers don't know anything about.